# how to pass a link to another components in react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, nodes, themoviedb-api

I am trying to pass a Link it has a films id to another component named movie detail js.
the problem I am having is connecting Movies Container link to movie detail. Please help

MoviesContainer.js

```
<Link  to={ `/movie/${films.id}${config.apiKey}` }>
     <button  className='successW' > GET INFO </button>
</Link>
```

MovieDetail.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import './MovieDetail.css';
import { props , match , params, } from 'react-router-dom';
//import config from '../../config.js';
import films from '../MoviesContainer/MoviesContainer.js';
import router from '../../router.js'



export default class MovieDetail extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state= {
       movie:[]
    }
  }

  componentWillMount(){
    axios.get(`/movies/:id`).then(response=> {
          console.log(response.data.results);
      this.setState({ moviesList: response.data.movie });
    });
  }

 render(){
    console.log( this.setState.movie);
     const imgURL= 'http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original';
       return(
           <div className='moviecd'>
             <img style={{ height: '85%', width: '100%' }} src={ imgURL + this.state.movie.poster_path } alt='movie poster'></img>

           </div>
         )
   }
  }
```

Comment: make it into a component and import it?

Comment: can you show me an example please

Answer (score 1):

ı guess you are using React-Router. First of all, you can specify the path you will use in the Router system and which component should be installed if this path is used. For Example :

```
<Route exact path="/movies/:movieId" component={MovieDetails} />
```

This is the system you should use for your router. 
and there is a button to go to the MovieDetails.js component. 
you should wrap this button with a Link(React-Router).  Like This:

```
<Link to = {{pathname: `${movieId}`}}> // The id of the movie you clicked
<button>Go Movie </button>
</Link>
```

Now, if you clicked on which movie you clicked on, the id of that movie will go to the MovieDetails.js component as a props.

If you browse the props coming to the MovieDetails component, you will find a props like params.match.movieId. 
You can now use this id when making a request (Inside the MovieDetails component). Like This:

```
 fetch(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${this.props.match.params.movieId}?api_key=<yourapikey>`)
```

How you process it after you get the data is up to you!

I hope it was understandable. Good Luck !